# Android FaceDetector.findFaces 100% CPU Time

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, face-detection

I got this simple function

```
private PointF getFaceCenter(Bitmap faceBitmap){
        PointF faceCenter = new PointF(faceBitmap.getWidth() / 2, faceBitmap.getHeight() / 2);

        Face[] faces = new Face[1];
        mFaceDetector = new FaceDetector(
                faceBitmap.getWidth(), faceBitmap.getHeight(), 1);
        int detected = mFaceDetector.findFaces(faceBitmap, faces);

        if (detected > 0) {
            faces[0].getMidPoint(faceCenter);
        }

        return faceCenter;
    }
```

I use it to get face center so i can know where to draw my picture. I noticed that my UI thread become stuck all the time when re drawing..

So i placed this calculation on the `onMeasure` but still everytime `onMeasure` called UI gets slow..

I started profiling:

[image: DDMS Profiling]

I saw that `mFaceDetector.findFaces` takes 100% CPU Time!!
I removed the face detection code and my app started running super fast.

**Anything I'm doing wrong?**

**Any workaround ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing that on the main thread. That the same thread that processes UI events.
That's the reason UI blocks. Try using using deferent thread to do computation. (see AsyncTask android documentation)

As for cpu usage - it has to process a lot of data ( especially if you have 10MPics camera :)) so it is normal.

The next pitfall is that current implementation only works for RGB_565 (again android docs) so it might be worth to check bitmap config

EDIT:

I just checked this on Galaxy S3 - for back camera made picture it takes arount 16 sec to analyse picture.